# Does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'. TS2339

Tags: react-redux, store, reducers

I am trying to implement react-redux in login-form input values.
I have added values to the redux state, but I cannot access the data individually from the state object.

Here are the details:

In `App.js` file

```
console.log(useSelector((state) => state));
```

gives result `{email: "demo@demo.com" , password: "123456"}`
. I am not able to access the email inside the state object using

```
console.log(useSelector((state) => state.email));
```

It is giving the error that
`'email' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'.  TS2339`

Here is the `reducer.js` file

```
let formValues = {
email: "",
password: "",
};

export const inputReducer = (state = formValues, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "inputValue":
      return { ...state, [action.name]: action.inputValue };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Here is the `action.txt` file

```
export const handleChange = (name: string, inputValue: string) => {
    return {
      type: "inputValue",
      name: name,
      inputValue: inputValue,
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function to get rid of this problem :

```
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, propertyName: K): T[K] {
    return o[propertyName]; // o[propertyName] is of type T[K]
}
```

You have to pass your object as first parameter, then the name of your property (here it is email or password).

If you want to get all your property at once, you have to encapsulate them in an object property like this:

```
{ value : {email:"alan.turing@gmail.com",password:"123" } }
```

Comment: this answer does not help me but the question is exactly the same problem as I have. I am using javascript not typescript in my react app.

Comment: @artworkjpm did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

i may be late but thought to provide solution. Basically this type of error message appears when you don't provide the typing in the `useSelector` hook

As per the doc [React-Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript) which states:

> Using configureStore should not need any additional typings. You will,
> however, want to extract the RootState type and the Dispatch type so
> that they can be referenced as needed.

here in your code block the RootState type is missing, this can be declared in your store file as below

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
----------
const store = createStore(rootReducer);
export default store;

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

And in your .tsx or .jsx file where exactly you want to access your store values using react-redux hook `useSelector` add the type as below.

```
useSelector((state:RootState) => state)
```